# Excel File Size

Tags: excel, filesize

I have an Excel Sheet with about 76.000 rows and 50 Columns. All is just plain text. The saved Excel file is about 16Mb. Is this realistic as the file size seems a bit big too me.

Best
syrvn

Comment: Big excel sheets gets always very slow, I think its just a bad optimized system.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.quora.com/Roughly-how-big-is-an-Excel-file-containing-1-million-rows-and-20-columns), it seems pretty normal

Comment: Save it as an XLSB (Excel Binary workbook).

Answer (score 1):

I think that 16Mb is could be too much for your file.
Sometimes big excel sheet (expecially if there are pivot tables inside them) have oversize weight if saved with old Excel versions...like Excel 2003, or if they are being saved with different versions multiple times...for Example Excel 2003, then Excel 2010, then again Excel 2003, ...

The best way is to copy all your table into another brand new file and save it, this will have smaller size than the first because you left all unuseful data into the old one.

Another way is to run the Excel Diet macro that you can find [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=83).

```
Option Explicit 

Sub ExcelDiet() 

    Dim j               As Long 
    Dim k               As Long 
    Dim LastRow         As Long 
    Dim LastCol         As Long 
    Dim ColFormula      As Range 
    Dim RowFormula      As Range 
    Dim ColValue        As Range 
    Dim RowValue        As Range 
    Dim Shp             As Shape 
    Dim ws              As Worksheet 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

    On Error Resume Next 

    For Each ws In Worksheets 
        With ws 
             'Find the last used cell with a formula and value
             'Search by Columns and Rows
            On Error Resume Next 
            Set ColFormula = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            Set ColValue = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            Set RowFormula = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            Set RowValue = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 
            On Error GoTo 0 

             'Determine the last column
            If ColFormula Is Nothing Then 
                LastCol = 0 
            Else 
                LastCol = ColFormula.Column 
            End If 
            If Not ColValue Is Nothing Then 
                LastCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastCol, ColValue.Column) 
            End If 

             'Determine the last row
            If RowFormula Is Nothing Then 
                LastRow = 0 
            Else 
                LastRow = RowFormula.Row 
            End If 
            If Not RowValue Is Nothing Then 
                LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastRow, RowValue.Row) 
            End If 

             'Determine if any shapes are beyond the last row and last column
            For Each Shp In .Shapes 
                j = 0 
                k = 0 
                On Error Resume Next 
                j = Shp.TopLeftCell.Row 
                k = Shp.TopLeftCell.Column 
                On Error GoTo 0 
                If j > 0 And k > 0 Then 
                    Do Until .Cells(j, k).Top > Shp.Top + Shp.Height 
                        j = j + 1 
                    Loop 
                    If j > LastRow Then 
                        LastRow = j 
                    End If 
                    Do Until .Cells(j, k).Left > Shp.Left + Shp.Width 
                        k = k + 1 
                    Loop 
                    If k > LastCol Then 
                        LastCol = k 
                    End If 
                End If 
            Next 

            .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol + 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete 
            .Range("A" & LastRow + 1 & ":A" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete 
        End With 
    Next 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried that diet macro Nicolaesse? I'm not in my PC but I wondered now. This would be a good practice though. But don't it really effect anywhere / any formula?

Comment: @Mertinc I've used that almost ten times and I did not find any problems. It only look for right and bottom edge of the sheet and delete the format or unuseful properties outside that. It doesn't change formulas.

Comment: Thanks mate I'll try it soon. Cheers